# How to appropriately increment within a nested loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, count, increment

My whole life I been working with Java and I'm currently trying to learn python. I'm asked to calculate the score for Erica and Bob and show who won. Each letter is assigned a value given in the problem description. I created a loop and if statement to increment the counter for both but it's not working as it should.

here's the code:

```
def winner(erica, bob):
    count_er = 0
    count_bob = 0
    for i in erica:
        if i in erica == 'E':
            count_er = count_er + 1
        elif i in erica == 'M':
            count_er = count_er + 3
        elif i in erica == 'H':
            count_er = count_er + 5
    
    for i in bob:
        if i in bob == 'E':
           count_bob= count_bob + 1
        elif i in bob == 'M':
           count_bob= count_bob + 3
        elif i in bob == 'H':
           count_bob= count_bob + 5
           
    if count_bob > count_er:
        return 'Bob'
    if count_er > count_bob:
        return 'Erica'
    else:
        return 'Tie'
```

Comment: Those conditions should probably be something like `if i == 'E':` and so on.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
You need to fix your indentation and finish the problem specification.  You also need to trace the logic and values, so you can explain just where you have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in the expressions `i in bob == 'E'` and similar; what you want is probably `if i == 'E'` or `if bob[i] == 'E'` or similar.

As it is,

- `i in bob == 'E'` means `(i in bob) == 'E'`;
- the `i in bob` part will probably be `True` (`i` is an element of `bob`) because of the `for i in bob` loop, so
- you're effectively testing `True == 'E'`, so none of the conditions trigger.

Side note: for most data structures, `i in bob` will be true inside a `for i in bob` loop, but it's not a requirement; classes are free to define these two operations independently, or only define one or the other. This doesn't make any difference here, since `False == 'E'` would also not trigger.